# List of Elements to Boolean Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, data-structures, scipy

Say my list is the following:
`['cat','elephant']`

How can I efficiently convert my list into an array of boolean elements, where each index represents whether a given animal (of 10^n animals) is present in my list? That is, if cat is present index `x` is true and if elephant is present index `y` is true, but the remaining 10^n are all false.

Is there a numpy or scipy built-in that achieves this comprehension?

Comment: Google `numpy.in1d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here are several ways for achieving this:

### Map

Using Python's [map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) built-in function you can do that easily.

```
animal_list = ['cat', 'elephant']
your_list = ['dog', 'horse', 'cat', 'shark', 'cancer', 'elephant']
res = map(lambda item: item in animal_list, your_list)
print res
```

Output

```
[False, False, True, False, False, True]
```

### List comprehension

You may prefer to do that using `list comprehension`:

```
res = [ True if item in animal_list else False for item in your_list ]
```

### NumPy's in1d

If you are willing to use `NumPy`'s array for compact reasons, then you may do this:

```
animal_list = numpy.array(['cat', 'elephant'])
your_list = numpy.array(['dog', 'horse', 'cat', 'shark', 'cancer', 'elephant'])
mask = np.in1d(your_list, animal_list)
print mask[1]
```

For more information, read [the manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html).

**Note**:  if `animal_list` happens to be longer than `your_list` in this scenario, then the `numpy.in1d` method yields `animal_list` as the 'target' list, which means that across varying instances the resulting array would not have consistent dimensions guaranteed. [Credit goes to [XLXMXNT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2754854/xlxmxnt)]

### Native way

Simply looping over `your_list`

```
res = []
for animal in your_list:
    res.append(animal in animal_list)
```

Comment: Perfect, this exactly answers my question. As a quick follow-up question: there is no way to avoid needing to define `your_list`, correct? Because the dimensions of `res` need to be pre-defined.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you give more details what you're trying to do, we may have a better solution, though.

Comment: Voting this correct for the `map` approach – if `animal_list` happens to be longer than `your_list` in this scenario, then the numpy.in1d method yields `animal_list` as the 'target' list, which means that across varying instances the resulting array would not have consistent dimensions guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
import numpy as np

animals = np.array(['cat','elephant', 'dog'])
wanted = np.array(['cat','elephant'])
print(np.in1d(animals, wanted))
```

prints:

```
[ True  True False]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x in range(largerlist):
    if largerlist[x] in shorterlist:
        booleanlist.append(True)
        continue
    booleanlist.append(False)
```